# Issue while trying to compress PDF files into a Zip file using jsZip

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I've made use of the cdn for jsZip, and after referring to the official documentation tried to generate PDF files and compress them into .zip format.

Code:-

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.pdf", "Hello World\n");
zip.file("Alphabet.pdf", "abcdef\n");
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

But, the problem I'm facing here is that although I'm able to finally generate the .zip file. I'm not able to read the PDF file, as it keeps saying that the format is corrupted. (The same thing happens even for .xls/xlsx format, I don't face the same issue for .doc and .txt format files.)

[the error message on trying to open PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJgu7.png)

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to additionally do? This has got me in a fix! Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:-
@Fefux - I tried something along these lines i.e generating pdf content first and then compressing to .zip, but it's not working either!

```
function create_zip() {
            var dynamicSITHtml = '<div class="container"><div class="row margin-top">';
            dynamicSITHtml = dynamicSITHtml + '<table><thead><tr><th>Target Date/Time</th><th>Referred To Role</th><th>Description</th><th>Priority</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
            dynamicSITHtml = dynamicSITHtml + '</tbody></table></div></div>';
            $scope.dymanicSITHtml = dynamicSITHtml;


            var pdf1 = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            var ElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            pdf1.fromHTML($scope.dymanicSITHtml, 10, 10, {
                'width': 1000,
                'elementHandlers': ElementHandlers
            });
            //pdf1.save($scope.operation.ReferenceNumber + '_task_summary_report.pdf');

            var zip = new JSZip();
            zip.file("Hello.pdf", pdf1.save($scope.operation.ReferenceNumber + '_task_summary_report.pdf'));
            zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
            .then(function (content) {
                saveAs(content, "example.zip");
            });
```

Please help!!

Here's an updated code copy.....
I've tried to make use of js-xlsx library - https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx - to generate xls file and then zip it.
Please refer the below code..

```
 function Create_Zip() {

        function datenum(v, date1904) {
            if (date1904) v += 1462;
            var epoch = Date.parse(v);
            return (epoch - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        }

        function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data, opts) {
            var ws = {};
            var range = { s: { c: 10000000, r: 10000000 }, e: { c: 0, r: 0 } };
            for (var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
                for (var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
                    if (range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                    if (range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                    if (range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                    if (range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
                    var cell = { v: data[R][C] };
                    if (cell.v === null) continue;
                    var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R });

                    if (typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                    else if (typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                    else if (cell.v instanceof Date) {
                        cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                        cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                    }
                    else cell.t = 's';

                    ws[cell_ref] = cell;
                }
            }
            if (range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
            return ws;
        }


        var data = [[1, 2, 3], [true, false, null, "sheetjs"], ["foo", "bar", new Date("2014-02-19T14:30Z"), "0.3"], ["baz", null, "qux"]];
        var ws_name = "SheetJS";

        function Workbook() {
            if (!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
            this.SheetNames = [];
            this.Sheets = {};
        }

        var wb = new Workbook(), ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);

        /* add worksheet to workbook */
        wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
        wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
        var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary' });

        function s2ab(s) {
            var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
            var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
            for (var i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
            return buf;
        }

        var jsonse = JSON.stringify([s2ab(wbout)]);
        var testblob = new Blob([jsonse], { type: "application/json" });
        console.log(testblob);


        var zip = new JSZip();

        zip.file("trial.xls", testblob);

        var downloadFile = zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
        saveAs(downloadFile, 'test.zip');
}
```

But, the problem here is that I keep getting this error: 'The data of 'trial.xls' is in an unsupported format !' in the console :(.
Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: Which version of jsPDF are you using?

Comment: I'm using jsPDF v1.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error because you don't zip pdf file. You zip a file named Hello.pdf and the content of the file is "Hello world\n" but this is not a valid PDF content (same things for Alphabet.pdf).

You need to generate a valid PDF content and after zip it.

EDIT : working jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/55gdt8ra/

```
$(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.setFontSize(40);
        doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");

 var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("Hello.pdf", doc.output());
  zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
  .then(function (content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi, how can i go about doing the same? Any options for generating PDF on the fly and then zipping it ? (I've tried to use jsPDF to generate PDF file and then tried converting into .zip file using jsZIp, but that doesn't work either. ) Any work-around ?

Comment: You need to find a js pdf library which can export your pdf as 'blob' (i think pdf.js can). And then compress this content with jszip

Comment: Hi Fefux, Yeah that's what I tried doing exactly, please refer my code edit above. But no luck :(

Comment: Hi Fefux, thanks for the solution provided above for PDF. I'm using jsPDF v1.3.2. Can you suggest how I can go about implementing something similar to convert .xlsx file into .zip format? (I'm making use of alasql library to generate xlsx files).

Comment: Sorry but I'm not that familiar with alasql and I can't tell you if it's possible. Read the doc and find a way to get your data as javascript string

Comment: Okay, but is there any way to compress xlsx files into zip (i.e the way an object of jsZip was first created and then zipped)? Perhaps by using any another js library ? Been struggling with this since 2 days, but not getting any solution :(

Comment: Hi Fefux, I've tried to make use of - github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx – Fefux - to generate the xls file and then zip it, but I'm faltering at the end. I've added a code copy above. Is something of the sort possible ?

Comment: @Fefux Is it possible to generate doc files using jsPDF ? If it is not can you suggest me some JavaScript libraries ?